xpath: como extraer texto de un elemento con id omitiendo otros elementos
quiero extraer solo el texto que esta en la etiqueta p
<div id="elemento">
  <p>
     <sup>link</sup>
     texto a extraer
  </p>
</div>

el inconveniente que tengo es que a la salida me agrega esa etiqueta sup; como puedo omitirla?
esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.
ver = drive.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="elemento"]/p')
for e in ver:
  print(e.text)


Para buscar un nodo texto con XPath utilizas la función text() de esta manera //*[@id="info_capitulo"]/p/text(), pero Selenium no tiene compatibilidad con la función text() 
Buscar un nodo texto es algo complicado, a mi se me ocurre usar directamente javascript para hacerlo:
text_content = drive.execute_script('return Array.from(document.querySelector("#elemento > p").childNodes).filter(a=> a.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).map(a=>a.textContent.trim()).join("")')
print(text_content)

Esto ejecuta un javascript que busca los nodos texto que están dentro de "#elemento > p" (con filter), se queda con el texto (usando map) y concatena todos los textos (con join)

hola, gracias por su amable ayuda, lo intente pero nose porque obtengo un error con text() quizas por lo que trabajo desde colab?

Lo ideal quizás sería obtener solo el contenido del TextNode, selenium al trabajar con WebElements está un poco limitado en este aspecto, en el sentido de que buscar un elemento y usar su atributo text (getText()) te retorna todo el texto sin más y es muy poco flexible.
No se si existe una mejor opción, algo menos "rústica", pero de forma genérica yo suelo recurrir a JS directamente para obtener el contenido de los nodos de texto hijos directamente, algo como:
ver = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="elemento"]/p')

for element in ver:
    text = driver.execute_script(
        """
        var text = "";
        for(child of arguments[0].childNodes){
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                text += child.textContent.trim();
        }
        return text;
        """,
        element
    )
    print(text)

Si tus TextNodes están siempre en la misma posición podrías simplemente indizar para obtener el nodo adecuado:
ver = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="elemento"]/p')

for element in ver:
    text = driver.execute_script(
        'return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent.trim();',
        element
    )
    print(text)

